# How to get the value of a td with id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of `<td>` with its `id`. When I am trying to get the value of `<td>`by the following code getting a `null` value.

```
function deletediv(ele){
    var r = $("#row_ #price_"+ele).text();
    alert(r);
}
```

here I am trying to fetch the value in `<td>`using `for` loop.

```
for(var i=0 ; i< data[1].product.length ; i++ ){
    var product_name = data[1].product[i].product_name;
    var product_code = data[1].product[i].product_code;
    var product_price = data[1].product[i].price;
    var product_qty = data[1].product[i].qty;

    var row_count = i;

    var cell = $('<tr id="row_'+row_count+'"><td>'+product_code+'</td><td>'+product_name+'</td><td id="price_'+row_count+'">'+product_price+'</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty_'+row_count+'" value="'+product_qty+'" style="width: 50%;" /></td><td> <input id="box_'+row_count+'" type="checkbox" name="cond_'+row_count+'" /><label for="box_'+row_count+'"><?php echo $lang_good; ?></label> </td><td><a onclick="deletediv('+row_count+')" class="btn btn-danger"  style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td></tr><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="pcode_'+row_count+'" value="'+product_code+'" />');

    $('#addItemWrp').append(cell);
}
```

Comment: since you want to deleterow - why not `onclick="deletediv(this)"` with `$(ele).closest('tr').remove())` inside of `deletediv`?

Comment: What is the value of 'ele' being passed in?

Comment: I want to delete the row as well as get the price from that row and reduce the price value from the grand total.

Comment: @DavidThomas id's are generating unique please check the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxgalrg64ndxbpd/Screenshot%202018-07-02%2019.05.08.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong because there is nothing with id `row_`. Instead of looking for the row then the cell in the selector just look for the cell since ids should be unique.

```js
var data = [0,{}];
data[1].product = [{
product_name: 'SO',
product_code: 0,
price: 1000000000,
qty: 1
}];

for(var i=0 ; i< data[1].product.length ; i++ ){
    var product_name = data[1].product[i].product_name;
    var product_code = data[1].product[i].product_code;
    var product_price = data[1].product[i].price;
    var product_qty = data[1].product[i].qty;

    var row_count = i;

    var cell = $('<tr id="row_'+row_count+'"><td>'+product_code+'</td><td>'+product_name+'</td><td id="price_'+row_count+'">'+product_price+'</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty_'+row_count+'" value="'+product_qty+'" style="width: 50%;" /></td><td> <input id="box_'+row_count+'" type="checkbox" name="cond_'+row_count+'" /><label for="box_'+row_count+'"><?php echo $lang_good; ?></label> </td><td><a onclick="deletediv('+row_count+')" class="btn btn-danger"  style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td></tr><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="pcode_'+row_count+'" value="'+product_code+'" />');

    $('#addItemWrp').append(cell);
}


function deletediv(ele){
    var r = $("#price_"+ele).text();
    var row = $("#row_"+ele);
    alert(r);
}
```

```css
.btn{
width:2.5em;
height: 1em;
display:inline-block;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="addItemWrp"></table>
```

Comment: Sorry but i tried this earlier, getting null value in alert

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a correct selector `var r = $("#row_ #price_"+ele).text();` 
ID suppose to be unique in entire document. So, do not combine your two ids as one selector. Use `$('#row_'+ele)` or `$('#price_'+ele)`

Comment: what should i do, i applied every code but not getting the desired result.

Comment: It would be better if you upload screenshots as well, to see when and where is getting null

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>test1</td>
            <td id="td1">test2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <script>

            var sText = document.getElementById("td1").innerText;
            alert (sText);

    </script>
```